# No route matches [POST] "/sessions_contact/new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

how are you? I hope you're doing well, I'm telling you, I'm doing a login so that users can enter and this entry is registered, I already have the Devise gem, but I do that so that the client (company) can log in, this is for users of the company I logged in.

the error is the following:
No route matches [POST] "/sessions_contact/new"

my routes are:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 
  devise_for :users

  root to: 'pages#home'
    
  resources :admins
  resources :clients do
    resources :change_policies, only: %i[ index new create edit update destroy]
    resources :age_policies, only: %i[index new create edit update destroy]
    resources :refund_policies, only: %i[index new create edit update destroy]
    resources :reservation_policies, only: %i[index new create edit update destroy]
    resources :cancel_policies, only: %i[index new create edit update destroy]
    resources :rooms, only: %i[index new create edit update destroy]
    resources :contacts, only: %i[index new create edit update destroy]
    resources :reservations, only: %i[index new create edit update show destroy]    
  end

  resources :reservation, only: %i[index] do
    resources :item_reservations, only: %i[index new create edit update destroy]
    resources :user_reservations, only: %i[index new create edit update destroy]
    resources :other_reservations, only: %i[index new create edit update destroy]
    resources :obs_reservations, only: %i[index new create edit update destroy]
  end
 
  resources :registrations, only: %i[new create]
  resources :sessions_contact, only: %i[index new create destroy]
    
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

I previously posted a similar problem and they advised me to make a new driver, which I did but it still gives me the same problem if you can help me Thank you

Comment: You `routes.rb` defines: `[POST] "/sessions_contact` and `[GET] "/sessions_contact/new"`. What does your form look like?

Comment: According to your error message you are trying to make a request with post method to  `/sessions_contact/new` page which should have been made by with get method.

Comment: resources :sessions_contact, only: %i[index new create destroy] in my understanding this code is the one that replaces the get and post or it is not like that and what you tell me does not work

Comment: Forms, like the login form, usually use `POST` it seems like your login form sends its data to `/sessions_contact/new` instead of `/sessions_contact`. That might be the issue and therefore I ask for what the source code of your form looks like.

Comment: You use get when you don't pass data in a form. Then Get is used for the "new" route, which is the route that displays the form. Once you have filled the form, you need to hit the create route with a Post method. You can do a `rails routes` in the console to check routes and associated method.

Comment: You should be able to see all the routes you have by doing `rails routes`  in the terminal of your project root.